# Is there a naming convention for Django apps

Tags: django, naming-conventions, django-apps

Is there a preferred naming convention for creating a Django app consisting of more than one word? For instance, which of the following is preferred?

1. `my_django_app`
2. <strike>`my-django-app`</strike> **Update:** Not allowed syntactically
3. `mydjangoapp`  **Recommended solution**

While <strike>all of them may be</strike> *options 1 and 3 are* syntactically allowed, is there a preference? Looking at the way Django creates the table names by combining the app name and the model name with an underscore, I'm leaning against option #1.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

They must be valid package names. That rules out 2 ("import my-django-app" would be a syntax error). [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.  Underscores can be used
>   in the module name if it improves readability.  Python packages should
>   also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is
>   discouraged.

So, 1 and 3 are both valid, but 3 would be the recommended approach.

Comment: A helpful blog post about this issue, just to expand: http://streamhacker.com/2011/01/03/django-application-conventions/

Comment: Hi @surfer190 . Two scoops of Django contains a ton of good practices. They choose the singular: blog. It is the same choice when you are creating a Model: Blog is preferred above Blogs.

Comment: In general, I would recommend using underscores, because they improve readability and they are commonly used, for example I use django_extensions and django_debug_toolbar a lot.

Comment: @WimFeijen, it seems that Two scoops of Django, at least [here](https://pt.slideshare.net/accavdar/django-best-practices-46944311), recommends using 'plural version of the app's main model' for app names, with exceptions like an app named blog, a 'good exception'.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks @Caco for looking into this and educating me.

Comment: Just curious any use the app name like "main" or similar name that can represents almost anything. coz sometime i feel like the app i am dealing with has larger scope than the named app.

Answer (score 41):

**some good examples**

- graphene_django
- users
- orders
- oauth2_provider
- rest_framework
- polls

in simple terms, `app_name` should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. also should have a short name and it can be a plural and singular name

Answer (score 9):

App directory names must be a valid Python package name. This means that option 2 is completely inadmissible as a package name, although it can still be used for other purposes, such as documentation. In the end it comes down to personal style. If you prefer option 3 then use it.

Answer (score 0):

My votes for 1 and 3, but you can check several popular apps:
http://www.django-cms.org/
http://geodjango.org/

Comment: Even more apps are here: https://djangopackages.org/ . Mind that packages are often named using minuses: django-debug-toolbar, while you have to use "django_debug_toolbar" in your INSTALLED_APPS setting.