# Is there a naming convention for Django project/configuration directory?

Tags: django

I'm referring to directory holding `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` ([Two Scoops of Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981467342) refers to this as the 'configuration root', for what it's worth)

I've seen people name this directory after the actual project name ([the official Django tutorial does this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)) but that leads to a redundant/confusing directory structure like the following:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app1/
    app2/
```

seems like it'd be more clear to have something like the following:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    conf/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app1/
    app2/
```

I see that there is already a question about [Django **app** naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098681/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-django-apps) but couldn't find anything regarding the project/conf directory.

To be clear, I'm asking about what to **name** the directory, not formatting conventions (underscores, lowercase vs. upper, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

There is some good discussion on this topic [here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/project-naming-conventions/339). Some generic options are project, config, core, base. I'm partial to "project" (/mysite/project/settings.py etc). To set up a new project like this, cd into your empty base directory and run `django-admin startproject project .`.

I've never been a fan of the default convention. It seems redundant and often conflicts with what I want to name my "main app". For example, I want to make a time tracking site, so I call my project "timers" (/timers/timers/settings.py etc). But now I can't start an app called timers, which is the best name for the app where I keep the timer model etc. If I name my project "project" then I can still have an app called "timers".

```
timers/
  manage.py
  project/
    settings.py
  timers/
    models.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use the pattern which you use for any package or module. 
1.  small letter 
2. Underscore (_) if needed.
If you don't want to use redundant name you just add dot(.) after a space after roject creation command. 

`django-admin.py startproject myproject .`

Comment: asking about name itself vs. formatting, edited question to make this more clear